# Activate virtualenv in chef and run gunicorn

Tags: chef-infra, gunicorn

virtualenv can be turned on by running activate from virtualenv bin directory. I had issues turning on django service using gunicorn. I got a libclsnth.12.1 no shared object error when I tried running the command inside bash resource in chef recipe. When i tried it running manually inside virtualenv it worked. ANy suggestions why its happening?

Comment: could you expose your recipe code ? are you activating virtualenv before starting the service ?

Comment: Yeah I am turning on the virtualenv before the service         script "Start service" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "root"
  group "root"
  cwd "#{virtualenv_path}/src"
  ENV['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/opt/instantclient_12_1'
  code <<-EOH
  source #{virtualenv_path}/bin activate
  nohup #{virtualenv_path}/bin/gunicorn application_name.wsgi -c gunicorn.conf &
  EOH
end